# How to change SafetyNet version in a flutter app?

Tags: android, flutter, google-play-services, safetynet, safetynet-api

Google is not publishing any update release for my app because of this **warning**:

> The developer of play-services-safetynet
> (com.google.android.gms:play-services-safetynet) has reported critical
> issues with version 17.0.0. Consider upgrading before publishing a new
> release.
>
> Here's what the SDK developer told us: The SafetyNet Attestation API
> is being discontinued and replaced by the new Play Integrity API.
> Begin migration as soon as possible to avoid user disruption. The Play
> Integrity API includes all the integrity signals that SafetyNet
> Attestation offers and more, like Google Play licensing and better
> error messaging. Learn more and start migrating at
> https://developer.android.com/training/safetynet/deprecation-timeline

I changed the version of google services to 4.3.13 in **android>build.gradle:**

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.7.10'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.2.2'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.13'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        mavenLocal()

    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

And updated all dependencies, this is my **pubspec.yaml**:

```
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.5.2 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.5
  sqflite: ^2.0.3+1
  sqflite_sqlcipher: ^2.1.1
  hive: ^2.2.3
  hive_flutter: ^1.1.0
  http: ^0.13.5
  url_launcher: ^6.1.5
  photo_view: ^0.14.0
  cached_network_image: ^3.2.1
  facebook_app_events: ^0.17.0
  flutter_signin_button: ^2.0.0
  flutter_login_facebook: ^1.6.0
  firebase_core: ^1.20.1
  google_sign_in: ^5.4.1
  firebase_auth: ^3.6.3
  carousel_slider: ^4.1.1
  crypto: ^3.0.2
  uuid: ^3.0.6
  provider: ^6.0.3
  path_provider: ^2.0.11
  connectivity_plus: ^2.3.6+1
  device_info_plus: ^4.1.2
  purchases_flutter: ^4.1.2

  path: ^1.8.1


dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  hive_generator: ^1.1.3
  build_runner: ^2.2.0
```

my **app>build.gradle** dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.4.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
    implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

So what to do now? I can't stop using firebase auth or google sign in.

Answer (score 1):

Do you also get this error when running the auth function in Virtual Android Device?

`E/zzbf    ( 6464): SafetyNet Attestation fails basic integrity.`

I have started getting this issue yesterday and checked all the similar issues people had but unfortunately none have done the work for me but I would suggest to give the [Play Integrity API](https://developer.android.com/google/play/integrity/setup) a go since Google says on it's [documentation that Play Integrity will replace Safetynet](https://developer.android.com/training/safetynet).

1. Enable Google Play Ingegrity API through the Google Cloud Console; [https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/library/playintegrity.googleapis.com?project=[YOUR](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/library/playintegrity.googleapis.com?project=%5BYOUR) PROJECT NAME]
2. In case your app is already on Google Play go to Play Console, navigate to the Release section of the left menu. Go to Setup > App integrity. Select the Integrity API.
3. In app level **build.gradle** add the following line on dependencies; `implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-appcheck-playintegrity'`

Correct me if there are additional steps/requirements, I followed [this documentation](https://developer.android.com/google/play/integrity/setup#integrate-into-app).

Comment: Im doing the testing on a real device and firebase auth is working fine in debug and release apks. Did you succeed with the play integrity api at the end?

Comment: Testing on physical device works perfect in debug or release mode as you've mentioned. No luck on Virtual Device yet.

Comment: I enabled the integrity api in Google Console and added that line to the dependencies, still I get that warning when I upload the app bundle to the console! I don't know how to remove this warning